# Streaming videos from websites?

Tags: android, video, web, stream

I am trying to make an app that allows me to stream a video from a website and play that video in my app.

However, I would like to play this video from my app and not through youtube or anything else.

So you click a button and a video starts streaming and stays in my app and plays. Also, another quick question here, can I play videos from anywhere?

I think I read that it had to be .mp4 or something but im not sure.  How can I tell if it's .mp4 by just looking at it?

If I really want to play a video that isnt .mp4 (or whatever it's supposed to be) is there any way at all that I could possibly play it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way is to have a view dedicated to a Flash player which streams the video for you. You can generate the HTML at runtime and pass it into a WebView.

This is probably not what you are looking for because you mention that you want it to stream directly with Android. I thought I would put the suggestion out there though.

Edit:

You would use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Using the following function:

```
loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, data, mimeType, encoding, historyUrl);
```

You pass in a base URL, which in this case can just be file:///android_asset/ and the data is your complete HTML code. etc.

The data would be set like so:

```
String data = "<html><head></head><body>flash player goes here</body></html>";
```

You would set the Flash player to occupy the whole screen, so that the size of the player is then determined by the size of your WebView.

Comment: @peter Thank you for helping me, could you help me more? i am a noob when it comes to android development, could you show me or maybe give me a link of how to do what you said. about dedicating a view to flash player to play the video for me, how exactly would i do this? Thank you again, i appreciate it.

Comment: ha, I don't really know why I called u peter? I think I was a little crazy because it was 4 in th morning, my bad :-D. And thank u for your help again.